# regex Positive Lookahead failure

Tags: regex

In my regex construct below,

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1> will match the opening and closing pair of any HTML tag, while

 q(?=(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>)) this positive lookahead construct should match every q followed by a pair of any HTML tag.
```

The function below is returning null. But i thought it should not.

```
function regex($detail) 
{
    if(preg_match('#q(?=(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>))#i', $detail))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;       
}

$detail = 'q<p>is this my first post is this my first post is this my first post is this my first post is this</p>';
echo regex($detail);
```

However this structure below validates

```
q(?=(regex))
```

I would appreciate if any error in my regex function structure can be pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your back-reference refers to the wrong group. It should refer to group 2 instead of group 1.

```
'#q(?=(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\2>))#i'
      ^ ^              ^                  ^
      | 2--------------2                  |
      1-----------------------------------1
```

Comment: tried hard but this is way more simplistic to convey the point +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
q(?=(<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(?:.*?)<\/\2>))
```

You have messed uo with the grouping.Try this.`\1` is differnet than what you are expecting.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/31

If you dont capture the fist group,your regex would work fine.See

```
q(?=(?:<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>))
```

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/32